# databinding on custom view causes type mismatch

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-databinding

I have a custom view (LoadingButton) and when linking it to a variable in my fragment via databinding, it causes the following error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is View but LoadingButton was expected`

But when i use findViewById it works perfectly fine. How can I use databinding in this case?

Apparently, this question needs more text as there is an error message in stackoverflow which says "It looks like your post ist mostly code; please add some more details", so I guess have to write some more details:

code:

[FRAGMENT] LoginFragment.kt

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding
    private lateinit var login: LoadingButton

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.mainViewModel = mainViewModel
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initUi()
    }

    private fun initUi() {
        login = binding.buttonLoginLogin    // causes error
        // login = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_login_login) // doesn't cause error
    }
```

[LAYOUT XML] fragment_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.myapp.LoadingButton
            android:id="@+id/button_login_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

[CUSTOM VIEW XML] view_loading_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[CUSTOM VIEW CLASS] LoadingButton.kt

```
class LoadingButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) :
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val button: Button
    private val progressBar: ProgressBar
    private var loading: Boolean = false
    private var buttonText: String = ""

    private var textColor: Int


    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.view_loading_button, this)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LoadingButton, 0, 0).apply {
            try {
                loading = getBoolean(R.styleable.LoadingButton_loading, false)
                buttonText = getString(R.styleable.LoadingButton_text).toString()
                textColor = getInt(R.styleable.LoadingButton_textColor, 0)
                button.setTextColor(textColor)
                button.text = buttonText
                button.background = getDrawable(R.styleable.LoadingButton_buttonBackground)
                setLoading(loading)
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }


    fun setLoading(isLoading: Boolean) {
        loading = isLoading
        if (loading) {
            this.isClickable = false
            button.isClickable = false
            buttonText = button.text.toString()
            button.text = ""
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            this.isClickable = true
            button.isClickable = true
            button.text = buttonText
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        invalidate()
        requestLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to double check before I have a look into it, have you tried to actually build and run the project? Data binding can be a bit finicky when generating its classes.

Comment: @HenryTwist ah, yea. I have other databinding components (with normal views) in the same class witjout any problems. I cut them out of the code.

Comment: Where are you declaring `binding`? Can you add it to your sample?

Comment: And is "[CUSTOM VIEW XML]" fragment_login.xml?

Comment: the binding is declared in the LoginFragment (i added it), and [CUSTOM VIEW XML] is view_loading_button.xml (the view file of the custom view)

Comment: Oh sorry I meant [LAYOUT XML], but anyway thanks for the edits, where are you calling `initUi`?

Comment: ah, man. I accidentially cut it out, it is called in onViewCreated(). I just added the code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229484/discussion-between-henry-twist-and-hooni).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is some kind of bug as the code compiles on other user's IDE.
A workaround that works for me is by casting it explicitely (despite the IDE  protesting):

```
login = binding.buttonLoginLogin as LoadingButton
```